# Update all records - no condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

change all the **[Titles]** of a **sql table** without any condition

I used a loop but don't know how to affect all the rows within the **Update statement**

it should be easy one

something like :

```
WHILE @counter < 89 
BEGIN

    Update Products 
        SET Title = ('Product ' + @counter) 
        Where Title LIKE ''
    SET @counter = @counter + 1 ;
END 

SELECT Title FROM Products
```

Comment: So it appears you have the solution, what do you want to improve?

Comment: I don't think you even need to include the Where clause because it will then affect all rows, so UPDATE products SET title = (whatever);

Comment: Show use the whole code and we will be able to rewrite it to avoid the loop ;)

Comment: the code that I've written won't work ,, the condition seems to be incorrect

Comment: See my updated answer, that suits your needs

Comment: All the answers seems to be correct, maybe the database was locked By visual studio, don't know

Comment: None of the records will change! somebody please tell me why ?

Comment: Will try the updated answers, thanks, let you know the result

Comment: Finally it worked, Seemed that the answer was Double Casting the concatenation part, because of the datatype that was a unicode based string, thank you all, gave all of you +1 (If not is -1 by others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Update Products 
    SET Title = ('Product ' + cast(@counter as varchar)) ;
```

This updates all the rows with the same value

**BUT**

if you need an autonumerated different values, try this:

```
Update Products SET 
  Title = ('Product ' + cast(@counter as varchar)), 
  @counter = @counter+1 ;
```

It **definitely** work, try this

```
CREATE table t (a VARCHAR(100))

INSERT t VALUES('a')
INSERT t VALUES('a')
INSERT t VALUES('a')
INSERT t VALUES('a')


DECLARE @counter INT = 0

UPDATE t SET a = 'aaa'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR), @counter = @counter+1

SELECT * FROM t
```

The output is

```
a
----
aaa1
aaa2
aaa3
aaa4
```

Answer (score 3):

Try next query:

```
create table #T (id int identity (0,1), Title varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #T (Title) VALUES ('')
INSERT INTO #T (Title) VALUES ('')
INSERT INTO #T (Title) VALUES ('')
INSERT INTO #T (Title) VALUES ('')
INSERT INTO #T (Title) VALUES ('')
INSERT INTO #T (Title) VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO #T (Title) VALUES ('xxxxxx')

Update sub
set
Title = 'Product ' + cast(cntr as varchar)
from
(select Title, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ISNULL(Title,'') ORDER BY id ASC) as cntr from #T) sub
where ISNULL(Title,'') = ''


select * from #T
```

Answer (score 2):

just remove the where condition:

```
Update Products 
    SET Title = ('Product ' + @counter) ;
```

Comment: At first I was using this, but won't work , After the last 'Select' it always gives me the previous result set

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the Where - Section of the query and everything gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Test data
    DECLARE @Products TABLE(Title Varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @Products (Title) VALUES ('')
INSERT INTO @Products (Title) VALUES ('')
INSERT INTO @Products (Title) VALUES ('')
INSERT INTO @Products (Title) VALUES ('')
INSERT INTO @Products (Title) VALUES ('')

--Query    
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0

UPDATE p
SET Title = ('Product ' + CAST(@counter as varchar)), @counter = @counter+1
FROM @Products   p

SELECT Title FROM @Products
```

Comment: -1 Change your answer to suit the condition of "update all rows", and then will be +1 from me

Comment: seems strange , again no difference, In the temp table it worked correctly !